Using aliases in javascript files using tsconfig
I have a project that was created using Create React App, in this project the development is in javascript, but I want to use typescript in some places, initially I had jsconfig, which had aliases written with which I could write convenient imports, but when I added tsconfig they started to conflict and I deleted jsconfig, but for javascript files typescript aliases do not work, is there a solution for this situation so that I can use alias in both javascript files and typescript files?
tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "./declaration.d.ts"]
}

I tried to combine js config and ts config, but I got an error, I also tried to use just tsconfig, but it doesn't work for js files

what's the error you've got

@YuMiao Error: You have both a tsconfig.json and a jsconfig.json. If you are using TypeScript please remove your jsconfig.json file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
